# Python Argparse: Return only value without parameter name

Tags: python, argparse, cmdline-args

I want to access and argument from my Python script using argparse:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

# Required positional argument
parser.add_argument('mode', type=str, 
                    help='Operation mode. Either "one" or "two".')

args = parser.parse_args()

print("Argument values:")
print(args.mode)
```

The variable "args.mode" contains the parameter name plus the value, like this "--mode One". But I want only the value part ("One"). I know I could split up the string but I want to know WHY argparse returns the parameter name. Is there a way to tell it I only want the value?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. If I type `python foo.py a`, `a` is printed. If I type `python foo.py --mode a`, it doesn't recognize the `--mode` argument, since you added it as a positional argument.

Comment: You haven't defined an option; the code you show would be executed with `myscript One`, not `myscript --mode One`.

Comment: If you define `add_argument("--mode")`; it will work the way you want with `myscript --mode One`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you want to post it as an answer? It works so I will accept it right away.

Comment: What was the command line?  We shouldn't have to guess from the error.